# Долгий ли запрос EXCEPT с LIMIT в SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возник вопрос, предположим что в `products` 10 000 000 строк, в `orders` 5 000 000 строк, под условие `WHERE orders.user = '<user_id>'` попадает примерно 100 000 строк. База `PostgreSQL v11`. На сколько такой запрос будет долгим и тяжёлым для базы?

```sql
SELECT product_id
  FROM products
 LIMIT 1
EXCEPT
SELECT product_id
  FROM orders
 WHERE orders.user = '<user_id>';
```

Comment: Все зависит от того, есть ли индекс по данному полю. Если есть, то не тяжелый.

Comment: Правда тут проблема, что limit так не работает.

Comment: План выполнения (explain) посмотрите и сюда выложите, без него нет смысла что либо оценивать. Оптимизатор одинаковые свиду запросы может выполнять совершенно по разному, в зависимости от статистики по таблице

Comment: Да, индексы есть. btree